# Integral using LogGamma fails

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

For the Matlab code:

```
integral(@(x)(gammaln(x+1)+0.57721566 *x)./x.^2.5,0,1e9)
```

I get =5.469... (almost instantaneously)

Trying the equivalent in Mathematica 12.3:

```
NIntegrate[(LogGamma[x+1]+0.57721566*x)/x^2.5,{x,0,1*10^9}]
```

the calculation would not finish after a long wait.

Will you show me how to obtain the Matlab (correct) answer?

Comment: This integral does not converge for x->0. Due to Series it goes with x^-3/2

Comment: @Akku14 This is not true, `Series[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma x)/x^(5/2), {x, 0, 3}]` yields the leading term of $\frac{1}{360} \pi ^4 x^{3/2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12 \sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sqrt{x} \psi ^{(2)}(1)}{6}$

Comment: @yarchik, o.k., if you use EulerGamma. But OP never says, 0.57721566 is EulerGamma. The rationalized form does not converge.

Comment: Using `LogGamma[x + 1.]` keeps thing `MachinePrecision` and fast. (Doesn't fix the convergence problem, but shows why Matlab seems fast.)

Answer (score 4):

The integrand, with all numbers exact:

```
f[x_] = (LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma x)/x^(5/2);
```

Capture the singular behavior for small $x$ in the asymptotic expression for $x\to0^+$:

```
g[x_] = Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
(*    π^2/(12 Sqrt[x]) + 1/6 Sqrt[x] PolyGamma[2, 1]    *)
```

Integrate parts separately and add up: the singular integral is treated analytically in the first term,

```
Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}] +
NIntegrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, 1}] +
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, ∞}]

(*    5.47135    *)
```

If you need more precision:

```
With[{wp = 10^2},
  Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}] +
  NIntegrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> wp] +
  NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> wp]]

(*    5.471346135899603136108128448540649799821138398820913558897482509129509200122440032933242531582252312    *)
```

Comment: @yarchik I took the integration limit of $10^9$ to mean "integrate to infinity", in the same way as I took $0.57721566$ to be the Euler–Mascheroni constant. Yes, if the OP is actually interested in integrating only to $10^9$, other tricks may be needed, for example what you propose.

Comment: Yes, the upper limit is to be interpreted as infinity and the other number (constant) γ  as (correctly) surmised. Done because of the possible limitation of Matlab).

Answer (score 4):

You can get an answer almost instantly with

```
i1 = NIntegrate[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2), {x, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 20];
i2 = NIntegrate[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2), {x, 10^9, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 20];
i1 - i2
(* 5.46993572961 *)
```

Notice that by explicitly specifying the `WorkingPrecision` the singularity problem at `x==0` is avoided.

Finally, I would like to add why there is **a problem at zero with machine precision**. Compare

```
N[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10^-9}]
N[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10^-9}, 1]
N[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10^-9}, 6]
N[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10^-9}, 12]
N[(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10^-9}, 18]
(* -1.48426*10^6 *)
(* 3.*10^4 *)
(* 26008.7 *)
(* 26008.6912475 *) 
(* 26008.6912475495376 *)
```

As you can see, all arbitrary precision results are consistent, whereas machine precision is not.

Comment: I believe `NIntegrate` does not use `N[]` this way, but does something like this (probably while blocking `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision`): ``(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10.^-9}``,
``(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10`1^-9}``,
``(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10`6^-9}``,
``(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10`12^-9}``,
``(LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma*x)/x^(5/2) /. {x -> 10`18^-9}``. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue of Mathematica (rather than MatLab)

If you use 0.57721566 as constant, the integrand does not converge for x-> 0 (even not the rationalized form). Only for EulerGamma beeing the constant, it converges as Series shows.

```
f1 = (LogGamma[x + 1] + 0.57721566 x)/x^2.5;

ser1 = Series[f1, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal // Expand

(*   -(4.90153*10^-9/x^1.5)   *)

Integrate[ser1, {x, 0, 10^9}]

(*   Integrate::idiv:  "Integral of 1/x^1.5 does not converge on {0,1000000000}"  *)
```

NIntegrate explodes.

```
f2 = (LogGamma[x + 1] + EulerGamma x)/x^(5/2);

ser2 = Series[f2, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal

(*   \[Pi]^2/(12 Sqrt[x]) + 1/6 Sqrt[x] PolyGamma[2, 1]   *)

Integrate[ser2, {x, 0, 10^9}]

(*   5000/9 Sqrt[10] (3 \[Pi]^2 + 2000000000 PolyGamma[2, 1])   *)
```

With given workingprecision get the result at once.

```
NIntegrate[f2, {x, 0, 10^9}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(*   5.46993572961007   *)
```

Comment: Just curious, how long does it take to execute your last command? MA11.1.1 runs too long, however, splitting the integral helps as my answer shows.

Comment: @yarchik, last command is done in 0.078 seconds with version 8.0, and takes half the time with WorkingPrecision->10. But any attempts to work with MachinePrecision like MichealE2 propsed,  or simpliy 1. *f2 fail to converge. Strange.